# How to conform top glare to all child elements

Tags: javascript, css

### Goal

Make the `glare layer` on all visible children `like a clip-path`

––––––––––––

### Heads Up

Child elements can be any shape with any animation
Child elements can be any `svg` shape with any kind of `animation` attached to it
So glare must be automatically dynamic and conforming

––––––––––––

### What I've Done

I create an apple TV effect…
But the glare only works as a box on top of other boxes.
The glare does not conform to other shapes
`Example Below`

––––––––––––

### What I Can't Use

Canvas - `No Canvas Please - I'm not familiar with it`
Clip-Path - `Because child elements can be anything overflowing outside of the glare`

––––––––––––

### What I'm looking for

Some kind of magical CSS line of code that makes the glare layer conform to all elements under it… like a normal glare would work.
`Is this possible?`
Is there some way Javascript can glare it automatically?
Is there some kind of `mix-blend-mode` I can use to make the glare just work?
Or is this something that is just `impossible`?
Glare should not look like a box

––––––––––––

### What I tried

I tried to scale the `glare` layer to `scale(1.1)` and use some `mix-blend-mode`
But I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

```js
appleTV();

function appleTV(){
    appleTVComponents = 0;
    function rotateX(n) {return ' rotateX('+n+'deg)'}
    function rotateY(n) {return ' rotateY('+n+'deg)'}
    function translateX(n) {return ' translateX('+n+'px)'}
    function translateY(n) {return ' translateY('+n+'px)'}
    function perspective(n) {return 'perspective('+n+'px)'}
    function scale(n) {return ' scale3d('+n+','+n+','+n+')'}
    function section(s='',e) {e=document.createElement('section');e.className='appletv_'+s;return e;}
    function getWidth(e) {return e.clientWidth || e.offsetWidth || e.scrollWidth}
    function setPerspective(e) {e.style.transform = perspective(getWidth(e)*3);}
    function preventScroll(state) {if(supportsTouch){win.preventScroll=state||false;}}
    function preventDefault(e) {if (supportsTouch&&win.preventScroll){e.preventDefault();}}
    function isTouchScreen() {return 'ontouchstart' in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints}
    function child(e) {return e.firstChild;}
    function children(e) {return [...e.children]}
    let body = document.body,
        win = window,
        imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.appletv'),
        totalImgs = imgs.length,
        supportsTouch = isTouchScreen(),
    move = 'mousemove',
    start = 'mouseenter',
    end = 'mouseleave';
    if(supportsTouch){move='touchmove'; start='touchstart'; end='touchend';}
    if(totalImgs <= 0){return;}
    for(var l=0;l<totalImgs;l++){
        var thisImg = imgs[l],
            layerElems = [...thisImg.querySelectorAll('.appletv_layer')];
        if(!layerElems.length){continue;}
        while(thisImg.firstChild) {thisImg.removeChild(thisImg.firstChild);}
        var containerHTML = section(''),
            shineHTML = section('gloss'),
            shadowHTML = section('shadow'),
            layersHTML = section('layer'),
            layers = [];
            thisImg.id = 'appletv_'+(++appleTVComponents);
        layerElems.forEach((e,i)=>{
        let layer_ = section('rendered_layer')
            layer = section(''),
            img = e.getAttribute('data-img');
            layer_.setAttribute('data-layer',i);
            [...e.children].forEach(c=>{layer.appendChild(c)})
            if (img) {layer.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+img+')';}
            layer_.appendChild(layer);
            layersHTML.appendChild(layer_);
            layers.push(layer);
        });
        [shadowHTML,layersHTML,shineHTML].forEach(e=>{containerHTML.appendChild(e)});
        thisImg.appendChild(containerHTML);
        var w = getWidth(thisImg);
        setPerspective(thisImg)
        preventScroll();
        (function enableMovements(_thisImg,_layers,_totalLayers,_shine) {
            thisImg.addEventListener(move, e=>{processMovement(e,supportsTouch,_thisImg,_layers,_totalLayers,_shine);});
            thisImg.addEventListener(start, e=>{processEnter(_thisImg);});
            thisImg.addEventListener(end, e=>{processExit(_thisImg,_layers,_totalLayers,_shine);});
        })(thisImg,layers,layerElems.length,shineHTML);  
    };

    function processMovement(e, touchEnabled, elem, layers, totalLayers, shine){
        preventDefault(e)
        let bdst = body.scrollTop,
            bdsl = body.scrollLeft,
            pageX = (touchEnabled)? e.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
            pageY = (touchEnabled)? e.touches[0].pageY : e.pageY,
            offsets = elem.getBoundingClientRect(),
            w = elem.clientWidth || elem.offsetWidth || elem.scrollWidth, // width
            h = elem.clientHeight || elem.offsetHeight || elem.scrollHeight, // height
            wMultiple = 320/w,
            offsetX = 0.52 - (pageX - offsets.left - bdsl)/w, //cursor position X
            offsetY = 0.52 - (pageY - offsets.top - bdst)/h, //cursor position Y
            dy = (pageY - offsets.top - bdst) - h / 2, //@h/2 = center of container
            dx = (pageX - offsets.left - bdsl) - w / 2, //@w/2 = center of container
            yRotate = (offsetX - dx)*(0.07 * wMultiple), //rotation for container Y
            xRotate = (dy - offsetY)*(0.1 * wMultiple), //rotation for container X
            imgCSS = rotateX(xRotate)+rotateY(yRotate), //img transform
            arad = Math.atan2(dy, dx), //angle between cursor and center of container in RAD
            angle = arad * 180 / Math.PI - 90; //convert rad in degrees
        if (angle < 0) {angle = angle + 360;}
        
        if(elem.firstChild.className.indexOf(' over') != -1){imgCSS += scale(1.07);}
        elem.firstChild.style.transform = imgCSS;
        
        shine.style.background = 'linear-gradient(' + angle + 'deg, rgba(255,255,255,' + (pageY - offsets.top - bdst)/h * 0.4 + ') 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%)';
        shine.style.transform = translateX((offsetX * totalLayers) - 0.1)+translateY((offsetY * totalLayers) - 0.1);    

        var revNum = totalLayers;
        for(var ly=0;ly<totalLayers;ly++){
            layers[ly].style.transform = translateX((offsetX * revNum) * ((ly * 2.5) / wMultiple))+translateX((offsetY * totalLayers) * ((ly * 2.5) / wMultiple));
            revNum--;
        }
    }

    function processEnter(e){preventScroll(true);setPerspective(e);child(e)&&child(e).classList.add('over');}
    function processExit(elem, layers, totalLayers, shine){preventScroll();
        child(elem).classList.remove('over')
        child(elem).style.transform = '';
        shine.style = '';
        layers.forEach(e=>{e.style.transform = ''})
    }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
  
}

body {background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f6f7fc 0%, #d5e1e8 40%);}








.center{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.appletv {
position: relative !important;
margin: 0 auto !important;
    display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.appletv.depressed {
    margin-top: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.appletv_ {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    background: teal;
}

.appletv_container.over {z-index: 1;}

.appletv_container.over .appletv_shadow {box-shadow: 0 45px 100px rgba(14, 21, 47, 0.4), 0 16px 40px rgba(14, 21, 47, 0.4);}

.appletv_layer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


.appletv_rendered_layer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.appletv_rendered_layer > :first-child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 104%;
    height: 104%;
    top: -2%;
    left: -2%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}

.appletv_shadow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 30px rgba(14, 21, 47, 0.6);
}

.appletv_gloss {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*display: none !important;*/
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 40%);
}




[data-layer="1"] {overflow: visible !important;}

[data-layer="1"] > section > section {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(50, 141, 210);
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
[data-layer="1"] > section > section:first-child {
    left: -30px;
    top: -10px;
}

[data-layer="1"] > section > section:last-child {
    right: -20px;
    top: 50px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% {transform: rotate(0);}
    100% {transform: rotate(359deg);}
}



.appletv_gloss {
    /*display: none;*/
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.appletv [data-layer="1"] {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transition: .3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.appletv:hover [data-layer="1"] {
    transform: scale(1);
}

.appletv:hover [data-layer="1"] > section > section {
    animation: rotate 10s linear 0s infinite;
}
.appletv:hover [data-layer="1"] > section > section:last-child {
    animation: rotate 25s linear 0s infinite;
}

#hover {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 37%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <section class="center">
    <section class="appletv">
      <section class="appletv appletv_layer" data-img="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
          <section id="hover">Hover Corners</section>
      </section>
      <section class="appletv appletv_layer">
          <section></section>
          <section></section>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```